# AWS Glue reading S3 file client-side encryption using AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kms

Is it possible to crawl S3 file encrypted using CSE-KMS in AWS Glue? I know that Athena can do that, but haven't found similar functionality in Glue crawler

Comment: Do you mean standard S3 KMS encryption? I'm not familiar with CSE for S3... However I've been able to use a Glue crawler on KMS encrypted S3 buckets. It just works. But I'm not sure why Athena has a specific encryption option, but Glue doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think AWS Glue supports reading from client-side encryption. They have just added [server-side encryption support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-security-configurations.html), which is much simpler to support compared client-side encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Glue Does not support Client Side Encrypted data. It only supports AWS KMS-managed keys (SSE-KMS) or Amazon S3-managed encryption keys (SSE-S3). these are the only two currently available in encryption models in Security Configuration in Glue [1].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-security-configurations.html